# My graphic card no longer supported for WebGL2?

Tags: google-chrome, opera, webgl2

I noticed that WebGL2 doesn't work anymore in Chrome and Opera on Windows 10, but it still works in Firefox. I suspect the graphic card is no longer supported, because I didn't change any settings. How could I overcome this ?

I use this page for test: https://webglreport.com/?v=2

Comment: Have you updated your drivers to the latest versions?

Comment: I checked in device manager and is already the latest driver installed.
Chrome stopped working a couple of months ago, and now I noticed Opera doesn't work anymore also.
This is what I tried in Chrome:
- Settings > Advanced > System > 'Use hardware acceleration when available' enabled.
- chrome://flags, 'WebGL 2.0 Compute' enabled
- chrome://gpu/ > Graphic Feature Status, WebGL: Hardware accelerated, WebGL2: Unavailable.

In the bottom of the page is written: Log Messages: ContextResult::kFatalFailure: WebGL2 blacklisted

Comment: Sounds like your card's driver has security bugs. You might be albe to get a more up to date driver directly from NVidia or AMD or Intel depending on which type of card you have.

Comment: I didn't try this. Let's see if I find a better driver.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any newer driver, but I downgraded the Chrome browser to an older version, and now WebGL2 works. Actually, you can configure multiple versions of Chrome on the same machine for testing purposes.

Comment: Sure it works but they blacklisted your drivers because they found a way to hack your machine via the drivers via WebGL2. So by using an older version you're taking a risk Google wasn't willing to take. You can also disable the blacklist on the newer version by passing in --disable-gpu-blacklist in the arguments to the program.

Comment: --disable-gpu-blacklist doesn't seems to change anything. I use an older version of Chrome only for testing using a local web server, until I move to a newer card.

Comment: my bad. it's [--ignore-gpu-blacklist](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#ignore-gpu-blacklist) and you need to make sure all other instances of chrome are closed before.you run for it to have any affect

Comment: It doesn't work either. The only flag that seems to change anything is --use-angle=gl (in chrome://flags, set 'Choose ANGLE graphics backend' to 'OpenGL'), but it disables hardware acceleration in both WebGL 1&2, and the quality is poor.